# How to get formatted date from android DatePicker

Tags: java, android, datetime, datepicker

The android DatePicker provides the following callback

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
```

How do I extract the following:

- For `int day` get a text day such as Fri or Mon or Tue or Thu
- For `int month` get a text month such as Jan or Feb or Mar

So basically I want to get two different values, a day by itself and then a month by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM");
    String output = formatter.format(calendar.getTime()); //eg: "Tue May"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of "EEE" I was using "ddd". Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Find all available formatting options for ```SimpleDateFormat``` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Here's a small tip: Always specify a locale when creating a DateFormat object, or use one of the static factory methods such as SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstances(). Otherwise the resulting day+month text might be in a different language. In your case, I take it that you want the result in English no matter the device locale, so you can safely use Locale.US as the 2nd argument to the SimpleDateFormat c'tor.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```

Put in calendar object.

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.Date,day);
cal.set(Calendar.Month,month);
cal.set(Calendar.Year,year);
StringformatedDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your callback-listener class, apply a `SimpleDateFormat` to fetch day and month as texts - e.g. as follows:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePicker datePicker = ... // e.g. (DatePicker) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
datePicker.init(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
    new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        final SimpleDateFormat mDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US);
        final SimpleDateFormat mMonthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.US);

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            String day = mDayFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            String month = mMonthFormat.format(cal.getTime());

            // ... Do stuff with 'day', 'month'.
        }
    });
```

You can also get the full-length representation of day, month (e.g. Friday, November) by initializing the formats this way:

```
final SimpleDateFormat mDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);
final SimpleDateFormat mMonthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.US);
```